# What software do you use to write limits,integrals,sequences,etc?

Tags: math-software

I tried using office word and I couldn't copy paste my limits,sequences and I want help.Does anyone know what program can write the functions in bold as you do?I am new in this and I have no idea what to use.I'm asking for guidance.I am so sorry that I had to write my functions as normal texts but I don't know how to write them in bold as you do.

Comment: The typesetting language LaTeX?

Comment: You can use Lyx to make your life easier if you don't want to learn LaTeX in full. But if you are going to regularly type mathematics, LaTeX is the best way to go,.

Comment: For newbies in LaTeX there is a platform called LyX. You can typeset your document in LaTeX in a WYSIWYG mode. LaTeX is not itself a WYSIWYG system. The source file is compiled to - for instance - pdf.

Comment: Refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Morover editing any question you can copy and past the text you need. Let try you'll learn quickly.

Comment: You can right click a formula and select "Show Math As" > "TeX Commands" to see the TeX code for it. Then you can try to put it in a post with single or double dollar signs around, e.g. `$\int f(x) \, dx$` or `$$\int f(x) \, dx$$`.

Answer (score 0):

We don't write in bold. We typeset in $\LaTeX$, which is (and has been for many years) the best way to typeset mathematics (and a lot of things, when you know the right packages for the task).